# Deleting a specific cookie in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies

I know that we can set a cookie by setting the 'Set-Cookie' header in node.
We can access cookies set by the same website through the 'Cookie' header.

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Set-Cookie': 'name=Scott'});

res.getHeader('Cookie');
```

But how can we delete aspecific cookie in Node.js (without express)?

Comment: You can't. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130677/i-cant-delete-cookies-in-express/46130738#46130738

Comment: But there is a way to delete cookies in express!
How comes there is a way to delete a cookie in express and not in node?

Comment: Got it! Thanks For your help!

Comment: There isn't a way to delete cookies in Express, as my answer there explains. It can only provide a hint to the browser that a particular cookie has expired, but it's up to the browser to actually delete it (or not, as was the case in that particular question). The main hint is to set an expiry date that has already passed, which you can also do in a regular `Set-Cookie` header.